# Monitor detecting poroblem

Tags: 18.04, monitor

Ubuntu 18.04 Detects 2 monitors when I only have **one.** My monitor model is LG *LG22MP68VQ-P*. HDMI supported. I have to rearrange the settings to get the screen. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `xrandr -q` and find the false display.

Then get the full name from

`ls /sys/class/drm`

It will look something like "card0-DSI-1".

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

and change

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`

to include

`"video=DSI-1:d"`

or the equivalent of the card name you got from the `ls` command above and then finally run

`sudo update-grub`

and reboot.